# Python: How to make an integer represent an ordered list of the numbers before it

Tags: python

So I've been trying to figure how out how to print an ordered list of numbers that occur before a number, starting from one in python. Let me show you what I mean.

Here is my example.

```
x = 20
#I want to print this
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
#Another example
y = 5
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Is there any piece of code or built-in function in python that will allow me to do this?

Comment: You are looking for `range`

Comment: Exactly what @MadPhysicist wrote. Here is something to read about the `range` function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to print the numbers, you can unpack your `range()` object and use the `sep` keyword argument to add the commas:

```
>>> x = 20
>>> print(*range(1, x + 1), sep=', ')
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
>>>
```

For Python 2.x:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> 
>>> x = 20
>>> print(*range(1, x + 1), sep=', ')
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
>>>
```

This answer was inspired by [@Grimmy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124373/python-how-to-make-an-integer-represent-an-ordered-list-of-the-numbers-before-i/45124419#comment77219466_45124419).

Comment: Could be nice to explain what `*` does.

Comment: @Grimmy _"[...] you can unpack your range() object [...]"_ - or do you think perhaps it needs more explanation?

Comment: This answer is best answer

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) class. Normally a range initializes from a start value to the number before the stop value, so you need to add one to the end:

```
x = 20
print(list(range(1, x + 1)))
```

Using a `range` object has the advantage of storing all the information about the elements in a way that only requires the integers worth of storage. You can iterate over it and test for containment without spelling out all the list elements.

Comment: Since the OP specifically wants to print `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20`, maybe recommend `print(', '.join(range(1, x + 1)))`?

Comment: @SethMMorton you can't join integers, `print(', '.join(map(str,list(range(1, x + 1)))))`

Comment: @NickA True.  You don't need to call `list` on `range` either. `print(', '.join(map(str, range(1, x + 1))))` will suffice.

Comment: To correct @SethMMorton's example: `print(', '.join(str (n) for n in range(1, x + 1)))`.

Comment: @ChristianDean What's wrong with the `map` correction from @NickA?

Comment: @SethMMorton Absolutely nothing. I was just showing how your orginal example could still be corrected and used. But `map` probably is the better solution here.

Comment: Could just be `print(*range(1, x + 1))` if we still accept no commas

Comment: @Grimmy `print(*range(1, x + 1), sep=', ')` boom. Just use the `sep` keyword argument.

Comment: @ChristianDean or python2 `print ', '.join(map(str,xrange(1, x + 1)))`

Comment: @NickA Or do `from __future__ import print_function` and use `print` as a function.

Comment: @Also possible : `print(', '.join(map('{}'.format, range(1, x + 1))))` or `print(', '.join(map('%d'.__mod__, range(1, x + 1))))`

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop

```
x = 20
for num in range(x):
    print(num, ", ", end=' ')
```

Though you'd have to do a fence-post trick with the comma, so Mad Physicist's response is good.

Comment: It should be `range(1, x + 1)`. Also, `print(num, end=", ")` would work better. However, you are going to end up with a trailing `,`, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: Easy to read and understand for newbies as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
x=20                    #The number you want
y=0                     #Counter vaiable
while True:             #Infinate loop
  print (y)             #Prints y
  y+=1                  #Adding 1 to y
  if y == x:          
    print (x)           #If y is the same as x,then print the last number
    break               #Stops the program
```

Does the same stuff but might be easier to understand.